# R: Write arff with missing values

Tags: r, weka, arff, rweka

I'm constructing a data frame on R and want to export it to ARFF format. To do so, I am using the write.arff() function from RWeka library. 
However, when dealing with missing values (?), the output is like:

> @attribute atomic_comp_c
>   {'?',3014,3212,3226,3234,3236,3238,3}

Instead of:

> @attribute atomic_comp_c numeric

Does anyone know how can I export the data frame to a ARFF format correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just found out that the problem was reading the input dataset without stringAsFactors=FALSE.

Comment: The R command "str(myDataFrame)" could also give you this insight.